# Adding a delete button to UiTableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Since I am using a slide-out menu controller in my app - the swipe to delete on a UITablewViewCell no longer works as the pan gesture is used to open / close the side menu.

So, I was thinking about adding a delete button to show up on each cell all the time - so user can just tap delete to remove the cell.

I added this code to UItableView cellforRowAtIndexPath method:

```
    /* Remove Button */
UIButton *removeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
removeButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
[removeButton setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
removeButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.667 green:0.667 blue:0.667 alpha:1]; /*#aaaaaa*/
removeButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
[cell addSubview:removeButton];
[removeButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(removeItem:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This adds the button and in the remove method I am not sure how to go about actually removing the correct cell.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need index for the `cell` which has to be deleted when delete is pressed.

you can set the `tag` property and when button is pressed you can check the tag propery of the button which is sending event.

see below code,

```
UIButton *removeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
removeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
removeButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 30.0f);
[removeButton setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
removeButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.667 green:0.667 blue:0.667 alpha:1]; /*#aaaaaa*/
removeButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
[cell addSubview:removeButton];
[removeButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(removeItem:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void) removeItem:(id) sender
{
 UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

 int index = button.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (IBAction)removeItem:(id)sender {
     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
     CGPoint pointInTable = [button convertPoint:button.bounds.origin toView:_tableView];    
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
     //Remove the cell at indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//1. add tag to the button, for identifing later

```
removeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

//2. Get the cell

```
UITableViewCell *cellToBeDeleted = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sender.tag];
```